# How do I cross validate daily time series data

Tags: time-series, cross-validation

I want to cross validate various models to understand which one performs best. I have been referring to Rob J Hyndman's post 
here

https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscvexample/

But I am a little lost as to how to use it on daily data.

my daily time series data starts at 2015-01-01 and ends at 2017-03-31.

Specific questions include:

1. What should `k` be in my case?
2. In `mae1 <- mae2 <- mae3 <- matrix(NA,n-k-12,12)` instead of 12 will I use 365?
3. In `for(i in 1:(n-k-12))` will I use 365?

I have a very high level understanding of the code and I believe that is another reason why I cannot translate this to a daily usecase. Any help in clarifying the problem would be greatly appreciated!